# How do you use the font shorthand if your font has a space in it?

Tags: css

For instance

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');

div {
    font:12px black "Open Sans";
}
```

Isn't accepted by chrome, using single quotes or no quotes doesn't help either. How do you use the font without writing an extra line for font-family?

Comment: @Gavin tried just now, no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, the `black` is what makes that line of CSS invalid. `font: 12px "Open Sans";` should work perfectly (and does when I try on Chrome). If you're trying to set font color, do it with the `color: black;` property.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, Chrome doesn't recognise `black`, not `'Open Sans'`. Use the weight measurement instead:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800');

div {
  font: 800 12px 'Open Sans';
}
```

```html
<div>
  Some lipsum text right here.
</div>
```

`black` is not a recognised value for `font`:

> The font CSS property is either a shorthand property for setting
>   `font-style`, `font-variant`, `font-weight`, `font-size`, `line-height` and
>   `font-family`, or a way to set the element's font to a system font,
>   using specific keywords.

If you wish to set the font colour, you must use `color`:

```
div {
  color: #000; /*or color: black;*/
  font: 800 12px 'Open Sans';
}
```